# was be able to vs could vs would be able to (backshift)

Tags: phrase-choice

I'm always confused about the usage of "be able to."
I heard that you cannot use "could" in such an sentence about only one occasion:

I could finish the assignment within an hour yesterday.

instead of

I was able to finish the assignment within an hour yesterday.

Then, how can I say in such sentences? Is knowing better about someone an occasion?(if... as conditional clause)

1. I thought he could know better about me if I talked him about it.
2. I thought he would be able to know better about me if I talked him about it.

and in such sentences?

1. I thought he could learn about it through my talk, so I tried to talk longer to let him know.
2. I thought he would be able to learn about it through my talk, so I tried to talk longer to let him know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a website (English Club) giving the 'rule' you mention. What it says is correct. As a native speaker, I find it OK to use *could* in the context you give. However, your sentences are not idiomatic.

For one thing, we don't say *I talked him* - it has to be *talked to* or *talked with.* You can say

> I thought he would/could/might get to know me better if I talked to him.

To *let someone know* something usually means to give them a specific item of information. *My talk* sounds as though you are giving a formal lecture.

> I thought he could learn about it through our talk/conversation, so I tried to talk for longer to tell him more.